# Read and append file simultaneously [C#]

Tags: c#

I'm looking for a way of opening a file for both reading and appending. `FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.ReadWrite` takes care only of (over)writing the file and reading, not appending.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Open it with `ReadWrite`, but seek to the end when you want to write to it. The stream only has a single logical position - if it's at the end, you can't read; if it's in the middle, you'll be overwriting data when you write.

If you're going to be doing a *lot* of reading and appending, alternating between the two, it may be worth creating a temporary file with all the new data, and then only actually appending it separately when you've finished reading.

Answer (score 2):

The code sample below as per Jon's suggestion:

```
System.IO.FileStream strm = new FileStream("foo.bar", FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.ReadWrite);

strm.Seek(strm.Length, SeekOrigin.End); // <-- Seeking to end of file
```

Then you can do `strm.Write(...)` to write to the end of the file.

Hope this helps,
Best regards,
Tom.